# Extracting element between a tag within BeautifulSoup ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

While working with BeautifulSoup, I have managed to get a `BS4 ResultSet`. However, I am not too sure how to proceed further to obtain the numbers between the  tags in the most elegant way possible.

```
[<tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>0447</td>
 <td>0784</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1991</td>
 <td>3462</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5563</td>
 <td>6761</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7277</td>
 <td>8191</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8343</td>
 <td>9981</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>,
 <tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>0115</td>
 <td>0579</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1503</td>
 <td>1968</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>3087</td>
 <td>5119</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7155</td>
 <td>8322</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8500</td>
 <td>9988</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>,
 <tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>0215</td>
 <td>3049</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>4717</td>
 <td>4888</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5969</td>
 <td>7437</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7704</td>
 <td>9157</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>9772</td>
 <td>9815</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>,
 <tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>1818</td>
 <td>2552</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2959</td>
 <td>3338</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5245</td>
 <td>5734</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5891</td>
 <td>7119</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8102</td>
 <td>8434</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>,
 <tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>2148</td>
 <td>3049</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>4210</td>
 <td>4897</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>4981</td>
 <td>7083</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7643</td>
 <td>7913</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8605</td>
 <td>8836</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>,
 <tbody class="tbodyStarterPrizes">
 <tr>
 <td>1546</td>
 <td>1868</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2482</td>
 <td>2585</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2698</td>
 <td>2903</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2919</td>
 <td>3448</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8658</td>
 <td>9054</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>]
```

It is definitely feasible to use list comprehension and iterate through the tags, and replace all the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags with an empty string, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner (in-built) way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each `<tbody>` tag in the ResultSet, then find all the `<tr>` tags within each `<tbody>`. For each `<tr>` tag, we find all the `<td>` tags and extract the text between the tags using get_text(separator=' '). By providing a space as the separator, the numbers within each `<td>` tag will be concatenated with a space in between.

```py
result_set = [...]  # Your BS4 ResultSet

numbers = []

for tbody in result_set:
    rows = tbody.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        tds = row.find_all('td')
        row_numbers = [td.get_text(separator=' ') for td in tds]
        numbers.extend(row_numbers)

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what types of output you want. If you just want the numbers in `<td>`, then you simply can do this.

```
html_text = [...] # your html content
soup = bs(html_text, 'html.parser')
td_num = []
for tbody in soup.select('tbody.tbodyStarterPrizes'):
    for td in tbody.find_all('td'):
        td_num.append(int(td.text))
print(td_num)
```

Output:

```
[447, 784, 1991, 3462, 5563, 6761, 7277, 8191, 8343, 9981, 115, 579, 1503, 1968, 3087, 5119, 7155, 8322, 8500, 9988, 215, 3049, 4717, 4888, 5969, 7437, 7704, 9157, 9772, 9815, 1818, 2552, 2959, 3338, 5245, 5734, 5891, 7119, 8102, 8434, 2148, 3049, 4210, 4897, 4981, 7083, 7643, 7913, 8605, 8836, 1546, 1868, 2482, 2585, 2698, 2903, 2919, 3448, 8658, 9054]
```

If you to separate values in `<td>` based on class and `<tr>`, then you can something like this.

```
td_num = []
for tbody in soup.select('tbody.tbodyStarterPrizes'):
    temp_tbody = []
    for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
        temp_tr = []
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            temp_tr.append(int(td.text))
        temp_tbody.append(temp_tr)
    td_num.append(temp_tbody)

print(td_num)
```

Output:

```
[[[447, 784], [1991, 3462], [5563, 6761], [7277, 8191], [8343, 9981]], 
[[115, 579], [1503, 1968], [3087, 5119], [7155, 8322], [8500, 9988]], 
[[215, 3049], [4717, 4888], [5969, 7437], [7704, 9157], [9772, 9815]], 
[[1818, 2552], [2959, 3338], [5245, 5734], [5891, 7119], [8102, 8434]], 
[[2148, 3049], [4210, 4897], [4981, 7083], [7643, 7913], [8605, 8836]], 
[[1546, 1868], [2482, 2585], [2698, 2903], [2919, 3448], [8658, 9054]]]
```